# How to access data in .caf audio file and fill up an array with that data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, audiotoolbox

**Background:**

I am attempting to plot the data in an audio file (file type: .caf).

**What I have done so far:**

I am using the AudioToolbox and AVFoundation to record, playback, close, and open the file.

I have also figured out how to read how many packets and bytes the audio file contains.
I have also plotted a simple plot (not related to the audio file) using Core Plot.

**What I can't figure out:**

How to access the data in the .caf file in a way that will allow me to plot the data.

**My question:**

How to access the data in the .caf file in a way that will allow me to create an array that can be plotted?

I apologize if this question has been addressed and answered already.  If it has been, I would appreciate someone pointing me in the direction of that post.

Regards,
George

Comment: this one might put you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982596/how-can-i-access-extract-rawheadless-audio-data-from-a-caf-file-on-iphone

Answer (score 0):

I did this a long time ago using a feature of audio queues called offline rendering. There may be a better way to do it these days, I'm not sure.

Here's a good (but old) technical note for how to do it this way:

[Technical Q&A QA1562 : Audio Queue - Offline Rendering](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1562/_index.html)